# INotifyDataErrorInfo - Model or ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm making a calendar using WPF with MVVM, I have a model for calendar entries and it also has a view model. I saw examples of INotifyDataErrorInfo and in some examples it was implemented in the model while in others it was in the view model. Does INotifyDataErrorInfo belong in the model or view model?

Comment: usually to the ViewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view model typically. But it depends on how you define view models and models. What you call a model may be seen as a view model and then you should implement the interface in this class.

The rule is that you should implement it in the class that you bind to in the view. So if you bind to properties of the `Calendar` class, then implement it there. This effectively makes `Calendar` a view model.

If `Calendar` is some kind of domain object that you use across several different projects, you should consider creating a wrapper class (called `CalendarViewModel` for example) and bind to this one instead of binding directly to the domain type.

Comment: I kind of assumed it belongs to the view model but I just wanted to be sure and to know why. Thanks for the good explanation!